# Periodicity justification in Markowitz optimization

Tags: markowitz

Monthly returns seems to be the industry standard for everything. Markowitz used monthly returns in his original paper on mean-variance optimization, the efficient frontier, etc.

Did he ever provide any justification or reasoning for choosing monthly over weekly or daily or yearly?

Comment: Not that I know of.  The monthly and quarterly returns have the advantage of being not too far from normally distributed (unlike the daily and weekly) but I don't know if this was already established at the time Markowitz was writing his paper (probably not).